# How to clear login attempts of user in Laravel 7 based on their email?

Tags: php, laravel

Good day,

I am using Laravel **AuthenticatesUsers** trait, using `php artisan cache:clear` clears the login attempts however I am trying to implement an artisan command that will clear the login attempts of a *specific users based on their emails*, here is the `handle()` of my artisan command:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $this->argument('user_email'))->first();
        $request = new Request($user->getAttributes());
        echo 'Login attempts cleared.';
    }
```

I am able to call the artisan command I created however it seems that the user attempts is still not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, for anyone else having the same problem this is what I did
override the function throttleKey in the **LoginController** and **CustomPACommand**

```
public function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return Str::lower($request->input($this->username()));
}
```

Comment: While this is a workable solution for resetting a user's login attempts, it makes you susceptible to a DOS attack. By omitting the ip address from the throttle key, a malicious user could repeatedly attempt to log in using a known user's name and prevent him from getting in.